# listview with HashMap show only one data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, hashmap

I had referred to [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text) website from androidhive for doing my ListView with HashMap. I got no problem with getting the data from the database but my ListView just can show only first record of the table. I don't know whether the problem is in database or I doesn't apply for loop in main activity. If yes, how do I apply it. Please help me! Thanks!

This is my database for getting the data

```
public ArrayList<Object> getFood(String cID)
{
    ArrayList<Object> rowArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
    Cursor cursor;

    try
    {
        String sql = "SELECT foodName, price FROM food_table WHERE categoryID = ?";
        cursor = db.rawQuery (sql, new String[]{""+cID});

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            do
            {
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(0));
                rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Log.e("LIST ERROR", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rowArray;
}
```

This is my adapter

```
public class List2Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public List2Adapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d)
{
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    TextView foodname2 = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.foodName2);
    TextView price = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.price);

    HashMap<String,String> food = new HashMap<String, String>();
    food = data.get(position);

    foodname2.setText(food.get(MainActivity.FOODNAME2));
    price.setText(food.get(MainActivity.PRICE));

    return vi;
}
}
```

And this is my main activity

```
static final String FOODNAME2 = "foodName";
static final String PRICE = "price";
private void listMenu(String CID)
{
    LISTORDER = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);

    ArrayList<Object> data = DB.getFood(CID);

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put(FOODNAME2, (String) data.get(0));
    map.put(PRICE, (String) data.get(1));

    test.add(map);

    LISTMENU = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);

    List2Adapter adapter = new List2Adapter(MainActivity.this, test);
    LISTMENU.setAdapter(adapter);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are only adding one item. Update your `listMenu` method:

```
private void listMenu(String CID)
{
    LISTORDER = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listOrder);

    ArrayList<Object> data = DB.getFood(CID);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> test = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (int i=0;i<data.size();i=i+2) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(FOODNAME2, (String) data.get(i));
        map.put(PRICE, (String) data.get(i+1));
        test.add(map);
    }

    LISTMENU = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMenu);

    List2Adapter adapter = new List2Adapter(MainActivity.this, test);
    LISTMENU.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: It's work, Thank you very much. Thanks for saved me again and again =)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with your Query

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        rowArray.add(cursor.getString(0));
        rowArray.add(cursor.getString(1));

       } while (cursor.moveToNext());
 }
```